# Sorting two column header in data tables

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

This is my HTML Table structure. [image]

I am using Data Tables with Twitter Bootstrap to sort the table. I need to apply sorting for both the User#, Ticket fields in that column. And also for Full Name, First Name and Last Name fields. Full name field will be based on the first name and last name. How can achieve this?
I added the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeswarik/XdzeF/10/) for this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table#student').dataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 6 ] }
    ] });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the default sorting that shows when the table loads? And by row, do you mean column?

Comment: Yes. In header i have two rows. Sorting based on the two headers.

Comment: I added http://jsfiddle.net/rajeswarik/XdzeF/10/ for this